# The inverse of a certain block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be an invertible $k\times k$ matrix and suppose that $k \leq m$. How do I prove that
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix} C & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-k} \end{bmatrix}
$$
is also invertible. If $D$ is an inverse of $C$, what is the inverse of $L$? I know there is supposed to be a general method for finding inverses of block matrices, but shouldn't it be easier in this special case?
Edi: Apparently, it is supposed to be 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-k} \end{bmatrix}
,$$ but I don't see it, my calculations say that $$
\begin{bmatrix} C & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-k} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-k} \end{bmatrix} \neq I_m.
$$

Comment: @ThomasShelby Indeed, I and suspect that it is a very stupid one (mistake) I will edit.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Oh, it was very stupid indeed. For some reason I assumed that all entries of $CD$ would be equal to $1$ rather than only those in the diagonal when calculating the product of the block matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider your matrix as a diagonal $2{\times}2$ matrix with coefficients in the  relevant matrix rings: the $0$ at the end of the first row is in $M_{k,m-k}$, the $0$ in the second row, in $M_{m-k,k}$. Then we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}C&0\\0&I_{m-k}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}D&0\\0&I_{m-k}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}CD+0&C\,0+0\,I_{m-k}\\0\,D+I_{m-k}\,0&I_{m-k}\,I_{m-k}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I_k&0\\0&I_{m-k}\end{bmatrix}=I_m.$$
This corresponds to the point of view adopted in Birkhoff-MacLane's *Algebra*.